# Images set for specific screen size

Tags: android, size, screen, drawable

Im making an android app and I want to use an imageview with height about 28% of screen height (eg 115dp for small, 127dp for normal etc). How many images should i put in my res folder??
I should do a separate image for each combination of drawable-[size]-[density] or just only for each density?